# Where can we see another user's voting record?

Tags: support, voting

I feel that for the purpose of transparency being able to see how much a user has upvoted or downvoted is important. I personally would like mine to be displayed publicly.

Comment: @Pëkka: I suspect because the title is ambiguous and people are assuming the request is to see specific votes from people, not aggregate numbers. That was my impression when I saw the title in the question list (but I did read the whole question once I opened it).

Comment: My question was with respect to the aggregate not specific votes

Comment: I can say that I downvoted it for lack of research, and for not even considering just looking at their own profile before asking the question to see if it was already there.

Comment: I did do my research. I looked around and I couldn't find how to see upvote/downvote history on other peoples pages. As such I asked a question. Perhaps a question that had a ridiculously easy answer, but a researched question nonetheless. Edit: Also I did look at my own profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The profile page [has been redesigned a while ago](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-on/), and some cheese moved.

The default tab when viewing other user's profile is "Profile" which shows things like Tags, Posts, and Badges.

The votes record is in the second tab, [Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity):

> [image]

Comment: Ah I see. I hadn't been aware of the redesign.

Comment: @MichaelGofron yeah, figured as much. :)